# SQLite Check if Table is FTS4

Tags: android, sqlite, fts4

I'm developing an Android app that uses a SQLite database with FTS4 tables.

In the app there's an option to import a database from the external memory. This database needs to be checked to confirm that it has all the correct tables and columns. I already have the code to do that however I don't know how to check if the tables are "normal" or FTS4. This will result in problems later on with queries with `MATCH` on them.

The only way I can think of to check if the tables are FTS4 is to do a random query with `MATCH` and if it gets an error it's because they are not.

Is there a better way to do this like with just a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MATCH on a plain table results in an error message only if the table has at least one row.

FTS table have a virtual column with the same name as the table name. So you could try a query like `SELECT MyTable FROM MyTable`.

You could check whether the [shadow tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_9_1) (`MyTable_content`, `MyTable_segdir`, etc.) exist.

You could check the CREATE TABLE statement in the system table: `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'MyTable';`

Comment: Thanks. I like your first suggestion.